# Laravel 5.6 not working translate in content

Tags: php, laravel, themes, translate

I want to use translate in another file than main file(file where i have some content and this file is extended by main file), but it is not working. Do you know anyone why? The same problem is with theme_url('path').

in main file i have:

```
@php
    App::setLocale('en');
    Theme::Set('mobile');
@endphp
head...
<body>
    @yield('content')
</body>
```

and in extended file:

```
@extends('main file')

@section('content')
    <img src="{{ theme_url('img/logo.png') }}">
    <span>{{ __('lang.title') }}</span>
@endsection
```

When i replaced @yield('content') by @include, all will be working(switching theme using from author igaster)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is that

```
@extends('main file')

@section('content')
    <img src="{{ theme_url('img/logo.png') }}">
    <span>{{ __('lang.title') }}</span>
@endsection
```

this code executed first and then put in main file
so in this file locale is not 'en'

try this

```
@extends('main file')

App::setLocale('en');
Theme::Set('mobile');

@section('content')
    <img src="{{ theme_url('img/logo.png') }}">
    <span>{{ __('lang.title') }}</span>
@endsection
```

Comment: Thanks, when I wrote the theme set and language set before extend all will working